# Trying to get this spreadsheet to highlight cells based on todays date

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So, I'm looking for a way to make the cell(s) highlight themselves based on todays date, nothing too fancy just so it's simpler to see the day. Pictured below is the graph I currently have.

[What I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCqf3.png)

I know it'd be easier for the formula if I were to just format the date as mm/dd/yy or some form of that, but it works better visually for the purpose of the form if it is done this way. So is there a way I could make it work how it is now? If not then what would be best with the formatting done in a mm/dd/yy format? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom CF formula rule-

```
=AND(A1=DAY(TODAY()),A$2=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try on range A2:Z:

```
=A$2&A3=TEXT(TODAY(); "mmmmd")
```